# Model a scalabe tag system for search google datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

What is the best approach to model a tag system for search in google datastore (ndb).

I'm thinking of modeling like this:

```
    Class Entity(ndb.Model):
          ...
          tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True, indexed=True)
          ...
```

I also read that this could be done using a mixin like [taggable-mixin](https://bitbucket.org/adamcrossland/taggable-mixin/src/a7738ff7216cb5fe2202a36c45e81b06b71f87b0?at=default).

We are expecting million of taggable records, and queries like:

```
 WHERE tag = 'value1' AND tag = 'value2'
```

what would be the best way to model this, in a scalable way.

Comment: Your proposed model looks fine to me.

Comment: Will this work/fit if I want a set of existent tags; or if I want to display the most popular ones?

Comment: You'll need to maintain a list of existing tags (update every time a tag is added). For most popular tag, I'd run a daily cron job and count all the tags - thus get the popular ones.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking in a relational way, but in this scenario is there any need to link the taggable entity with the tag list? like create a list of all entities that are tagged with a particular tag. Or can this tags entity, be used just for maintain a list of unique tags and popularity?

Comment: In this specific scenario no need to link entities, you can use this entity only to maintain the list. But in case you'll want to change tag titles, or add some sort of properties, linking of entities might be a better idea.